# Ocultar Log de la consola de Eclipse en JAVA

Tags: java, consola, selenium-webdriver, logger, edge

Al actualizar a selenium 4.0 en la consola ha empezado a salir un montón de logger y me estorba para ver las salidas que hago con System.out.println

Estoy usando para las pruebas el navegador Edge y programo en Java y puse estas dos líneas pero sigue saliendo el logger por la consola detallado .

`System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","./src/test/resources/Edgedriver/msedgedriver.exe"); java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.OFF);`

¿como se oculta?

Comment: agrega tu configuracion actual, generalmente se pone en resources. Si no tienes tu archivo de construccion para saber que framework de registro usas.

Comment: no entiendo bien lo que dices, estoy empezando con esta de programar . Es algún archivo o el contenido de algún archivo en concreto?